# Google Analytics - Some ecommerce transactions are not showing in GA

Tags: google-analytics, transactions, e-commerce, google-tag-manager

We have implemented Google Analytics Ecommerce tracking in our web site. We have noted that there are some missing transactions from Google Analytics. Only some data get missing and other transactions are recorded correctly.

There is no specific pattern to those missing orders (e.g. the products that are selected, the device they are using...etc).

Below is the code snippet that push transaction data to analytics.

```
    var products = [];

    for (i = 0; i < cart.lines.length; i++) {

                var cartItem = cart.lines[i];

                if (cartItem != null && cartItem != 'undefined') {

                    products.push({
                        'name': cartItem.cartProduct.name + ' ($' + cartItem.cost + ')',
                        'id': cartItem.cartProduct.id ,
                        'price': cartItem.cost,
                        'brand': 'My Brand XXX',
                        'category': cartItem.category,
                        'variant': 'My Brand XXX',
                        'quantity': 1 // Iterating item by item therefore hardcoding quantity to 1
                    });
                }
            }


            // Pushing ecommerce transaction data to data layer
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            dataLayer.push({
                'ecommerce': {
                    'purchase': {
                        'actionField': {
                            'id': cart.referenceNumber,           // Transaction ID. Required for purchases and refunds.
                            'affiliation': store.name,
                            'revenue': cart.totalPrice,            // Total transaction value (incl. tax and shipping)
                            'tax': 0,
                            'shipping': cart.deliveryCharge,
                            'coupon': ''
                        },
                        'products': products
                    }
                },
                'event': 'purchase'
            });
        }
```

Note that I have the fully populated 'cart' and 'store' objects accessible.
Appreciate if anyone could help to figure out what's causing this.

Comment: Are you sure those are not simply visitors who have opted out from tracking or use a software like Ghostery to block tracking tags ?

Comment: What error rate are you experiencing, I was forced to move this to the server measurement protocol, to ensure the transactions would 100% match. with JS this proved impossible due incomplete page load, blockers etc

Comment: @EikePierstorff There's a considerable percentage of transactions not being tracked. Not sure all of them could be opted out from tracking.

Comment: @MarcelDumont About 15-20% of the transactions, around 2000 orders per weeks time. How do you use the server measurement protocol? Would like to know more about it.

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/ for the protocol description. in practice you pass over the ga session id to the server, and call ga serverside through the protocol with the ga session id as a reference. In the call you send over the e-commerce transaction details.

Comment: We are experiencing the same in our setup and have tried all sorts of support sessions with Google and no one can explain! Wondering if @ksm got to the bottom of this?

Comment: I had the same idea as @MarcelDumont and am playing catch up via the Measurement Protocol to push missed transactions but even then,  only about 20-25% of my transactions show up.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Your code seems fine. There isn't any specific way to identify the way what is causing this issue.
You can implement exception tracking in above particular code, by that you will get to know the possible reason which is causing the issue.

To implement exception tracking using GTM you need to wrap up the above code in try catch block and in catch block you push the datalayer event with the exception detail. On other side in GTM configure the exception tracking tag.

Hope this will help you. Let me know in case of any help needed to implement exception tracking.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion ! How did you configure the exception tracking from GTM end? Is there a view/page on GTM that we can see exceptions thrown?

Comment: Well, really sorry to comment this late, but I was on vacation.

Comment: You can use event tracking...Follow the steps
1. Enable Standard Variable[http://i.imgur.com/3jXDNxX.png].
2. Create Trigger as shown in image[http://i.imgur.com/ZkyEdoq.png]
3. Create Tag as shown in image and attach above created Trigger[http://i.imgur.com/cRMhLF9.png]

Answer (score 1):

As Google Analytic is Javascript based platform, there could be a lot of reasons the transaction could be missing, some of the obvious reasons are outlined below -:

- Ad blocker is enabled on your browser
- JavaScript is disabled
- Cookies are turned off
- Customer left the page before transaction was sent to Google
  Analytics
- Payment gateway is not redirecting customers to your order
  confirmation page
- Order confirmation page may not load for certain payment methods
- GDPR extensions can also prevent transactions from reaching Google
  Analytics

In the past we have used one of the [extensions](https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento2-google-analytics-sync-for-missing-transactions.html) for our Magento 2 site to sync missing orders between Magento and Google using [Measurement Protocol API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters)

Whatever platform you might be using, Measurement Protocol API could be utilised to synch orders between the two system and give you 100% sales data view in Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a third-party payment processor for some but not all transactions - common example, you accept credit cards on your website but you also accept PayPal payments where the buyer is taken to the PayPal site to complete the transaction - the ones who leave your site to pay are often not counted.

Two reasons: one, many buyers leave straight from PayPal - they never view the order confirmation page where your tracking code is set to send the data to GA.

Two, they're tracked separately because they've technically left your website and then returned, so you need to set up cross-domain tracking to associate them with the correct user session.

(I know this answer is rather late for the OP but thought it might help someone else in a similar situation.)